Splitting and forwarding to bool_lazy_any in LaTeX3?
I currently have a function which does the following:
\NewDocumentCommand{\myfunction}{m m m}{
    \str_if_eq:eeTF{\c_sys_engine_str}{#1}{#2}{#3}
}

which allows me to do something as: \myfunction{pdftex}{TRUE}{FALSE}.
I would like to be able to write something like:
\myfunction{xetex|luatex}{TRUE}{FALSE}

and have the function to be relatively efficient. One way of doing that would be to split on the | character and inject the result into bool_lazy_any.
QUESTION: How to achieve such a thing? (if the function is expandable, it's better, but if not, it's fine).

Can you expand your code into a minimal example we can compile? That is much more useful than a mere snippet.

why start from the string rather than \sys_if_engine_xetex:TF amd \sys_if_engine_xluatex:TF ?

You can make the test expandable if, instead of | you use commas.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\myfunction}{mmm}
 {% #1 is a comma separated list of engine strings
  \vincent_ifengine:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \vincent_ifengine:n { p,T,F,TF }
 {
  \clist_map_function:nN {#1,NOTANENGINE} \__vincent_ifengine_check:n
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__vincent_ifengine_check:n
 {
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { NOTANENGINE  } {#1}
   {
    \prg_return_false:
   }
   {
    \str_if_eq:eeT { \c_sys_engine_str } {#1}
     {
      \clist_map_break:n { \prg_return_true: }
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\myfunction{pdftex,xetex}{\typeout{TRUE}}{\typeout{FALSE}}

\edef\test{\myfunction{pdftex,xetex}{TRUE}{FALSE}}
\typeout{\meaning\test}

\stop

Let's test.
Run with pdflatex
TRUE
macro:->TRUE

Run with xelatex
TRUE
macro:->TRUE

Run with lualatex
FALSE
macro:->FALSE

Run with platex
FALSE
macro:->FALSE

How does this work?
If a match is found before the last item (NOTANENGINE), the loop is broken and \prg_return_true: is issued. If the match is at NOTANENGINE it means that no previous item matched the current engine and we issue \prg_return_false:.

I am 100% confident that there is a better way to do this. But I'll leave this here waiting for someone to write a better answer. It does exactly what you suggest (and that's also what makes it not the best).
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_const_from_clist:Nn \c_vincent_allowableengines_seq
  { pdftex, luatex, xetex, ptex, uptex }
\msg_new:nnn { vincent } { engine-not-recognized }
  { Engine~'#1'~not~recognized! }
\seq_new:N \l_vincent_tmpa_seq
\tl_new:N \l_vincent_tmpa_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\myfunction}{m m m}
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_vincent_tmpa_seq { | } { #1 }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_vincent_tmpa_seq
      {
        \seq_if_in:NnF \c_vincent_allowableengines_seq { ##1 }
          { \msg_error:nnn { vincent } { engine-not-recognized } { ##1 } }
      }
    \tl_set:Ne \l_vincent_tmpa_tl
      { \seq_map_function:NN \l_vincent_tmpa_seq \vincent_myfunction_aux:n }
    \exp_args:NV \bool_lazy_any:nTF \l_vincent_tmpa_tl { #2 } { #3 }
  }
\cs_set:Npn \vincent_myfunction_aux:n #1
  { { \exp_not:N \str_if_eq_p:nn { #1 } {\c_sys_engine_str} } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\myfunction{xetex|luatex}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\myfunction{pdftex}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\myfunction{xetex|pdftex}{TRUE}{FALSE}

%\myfunction{luametatex}{TRUE}{FALSE} % errors

\end{document}

This is, of course, not expandable.
